# How to display selected item in a single-selection listbox in an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, selecteditem

I am coding a master file on excel, with a header on every sheet that displays data specified through a user form. 3 out of 5 controls work but the listboxes with the start and end dates do not return the selected values. Here are the code lines for the OK button of the user form :

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()

Dim s As Integer
Dim lStart As Integer
Dim lEnd As Integer

For s = 2 To 9

    Worksheets(s).Activate
    Cells(1, 2) = CompanyTextBox.Value

    For lStart = 0 To StartListBox.ListCount - 1
    If StartListBox.Selected(lStart) = True Then
    Cells(2, 2) = StartListBox.List(lStart)
    End If
    Next lStart

    For lEnd = 0 To EndListBox.ListCount - 1
    If EndListBox.Selected(lEnd) = True Then
    Cells(3, 2) = EndListBox.List(lEnd)
    End If
    Next lEnd

    Cells(4, 2) = RatingListBox.Value

    Cells(5, 2) = GradeListBox.Value

Next s

Unload Me

End Sub
```

My question is pretty similar to an unanswered question on stack overflow actually : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143420/data-transfer-to-excel-from-visual-basic-2008.

Also I have tried the `Date` and `String` types for `lStart` and `lEnd`.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the "Selected" property is useful when the ListBox property "MultiSelect" is set to "True". This means that you can select more than one item in a ListBox control.

When "MultiSelect" is set to "False", you'd better use the ListBox property "ListIndex" which returns an index value, between -1 and "ListCount-1", indicating which item in the list has been clicked and is apparent in the control on the  userform.

When no item is selected, "ListIndex" is equal to -1, the first item selected : 0, the last item selected : "ListCount-1".
Hence here is your code modified after what I wrote :

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()

Dim s As Long
Dim lStart As Long
Dim lEnd As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet

For s = 2 To 9

    Set WS = Worksheets(s)

    WS.Cells(1, 2) = WS.CompanyTextBox.Value

    If WS.StartListBox.ListCount > -1 Then
        WS.Cells(2, 2) = WS.StartListBox.List(WS.StartListBox.ListIndex)
    else
        WS.Cells(2, 2) = ""
    End If

    If WS.EndListBox.ListIndex > -1 Then
        WS.Cells(3, 2) = WS.EndListBox.List(WS.EndListBox.ListIndex)
    Else
        WS.Cells(3, 2) = ""
    End If

    WS.Cells(4, 2) = WS.RatingListBox.Value
    WS.Cells(5, 2) = WS.GradeListBox.Value

Next s

Unload Me
Set WS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: @Didi_Allo : I'm glad you appreciate my answer. Thanks for your vote.